# Send a string from windows to vmware-ubuntu over socket using python

Tags: python, linux, sockets, python-2.7, vmware

I am trying to send a string from the windows to the linux vmware on the same machine.

I did the following:
- opened a socket on 127.0.0.1 port 50000 on the linux machine and reading the socket in a while loop. My programming language is python 2.7
- send a command using nc ( netcat ) on 127.0.0.1 port 50000 from the windows machine ( using cygwin ).

However, I dont receive any command on the linux machine although the command sent through windows /cygwin is successful.

I am using NAT ( sharing the hosts IP address ) on the VMWARE Machine.

Where could be the problem?

Comment: Have you tried it on the same PC first ?

Comment: Besides port forwarding, bind to all interfaces not just 127.0.0.1 as it accepts connection from your VM only.

Answer (score 1):

When you use NAT, the host machine has no way to directly contact the client machine. All you can do is usign port forwarding to tell vmware that all traffic directed to the designated ports on the host is to be delivered to the client. It is intended to install a server on the client machine that can be accessed from  outside the host machine.

If you want to test network operation between the host and the client, you should configure a host-only adapter on the client machine. It is a virtual network between the host and the client(s) machine(s) (more than one client can share same host-only network, of course with different addresses)

I generally configure 2 network adapters on my client machines :

- one NAT to give the client machine an access to the open world
- on host-only to have a private network between host and clients and allow them to communicate with any protocol on any port

You can also use a bridged interface on the client. In this mode, the client machine has an address on same network than the external network of the host : it combines both previous modes

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is multi-fold

---

### <kbd>**1**</kbd>st

**setup** Ubuntu-VM's IP-network & a **static IP-address** of this guest O/S.

**VALIDATE:**

```
$> ifconfig                         // list all setup Ubuntu interfaces/addresses
```

---

### <kbd>**2**</kbd>nd

if your VM guest is hosted as being connected to a different IP-network, than your Windows system, **make sure there is a connectivity and route between these two hosts** ( VMnet configurator in VmWare will help a lot to solve this ).

**VALIDATE:**

```
C:\ ping <aUbuntuVmIpADDRESS>      // prove an online visibility Win->UbuntuVM
```

---

### <kbd>**3**</kbd>rd

**make sure** your Windows O/S **permits the use** your selected TCP-port#

**VALIDATE:**

> list all allowed / add if-needed TCP-port# in Windows Firewall setup

---

### <kbd>**4**</kbd>th

**make sure** your python sends all socket-traffic **not** to a Windows local loopback interface <127.0.0.1>, **but towards** the visible **IP-address of the Ubuntu-VM** guest O/S, ( setup as per step-<kbd>**1**</kbd>, verified as per step-<kbd>**2**</kbd> ) **using** an unused, permitted TCP-port# ( verified/setup as per step-<kbd>**3**</kbd> )